# How many sequences possible in stack , if the input(1,2,3,...,n) is in order?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, topological-stacks

> How many permutations can be obtained in the output (in the same order) using a stack assuming that the input is the sequence $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,\dots, n)$ in that order?

**Example** If $n=5$, then outputs

- $3,4,5,2,1$
- $1,2,3,4,5$
- $5,4,3,2,1$   etc.

are possible, and outputs

- $3,4,5,1,2$
- $1,5,2,3,4$
- $5,4,3,1,2$ etc.

are impossible.

Comment: Interesting problem. What are your own thoughts on it?

Comment: It's [catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-sortable_permutation) ?

Comment: Why is $3,4,5,1,2$ impossible?

Comment: @hjpotter, because you need to stack $1$ before $2$. And they will go back in the reverse order.

Comment: Please edit your post adding that you think these are Catalan numbers (and why do you suspect this).

Comment: push(1) , push(2) , push(3) , pop() , push(4) , pop(), push(5) , pop() ,pop() ,\*this pop can't give element 1 , infact , it's give element 2*\ 
so , output **3,4,5,1,2** is not possible . Am I rt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess about Catalan numbers is correct. We have a sequence of numbers (pushes), and each of them is popped at some moment. Write a push as a left bracket and a pop as a right bracket, so that, for instance, the sequence $3,4,5,2,1$ corresponds to $((()()()))$. Then we have a one-to-one correspondence with proper bracket sequences, which are enumerated by Catalan numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much , I got it .